# How do I calculate challenge rating against a player character?

Tags: dnd-5e, cr-calculation

I am trying to pit a party against a powerful, epic-leveled Goliath Barbarian, using the abilities he would have as a player character. I do not want to make him too powerful, but I still want him to reflect the epic status he is supposed to hold.

Are there guidelines for how to calculate this challenge rating?

Notes:

- I'm not horribly interested in frame challenges here, unless there's a really good reason for it. This is a casual one-shot for my family, not an AL public game.
- The party will be from 4-7 people, all at level 3. One of them (my dad) played in college, so several editions ago, and other than that, there's very little experience with the game. I don't know how useful this is to answerers, but my goal is definitely to err on the side of easier, rather than harder, because of their lack of experience.
- For those familiar with it, I'm going to be using the Tal'dorei setting (specifically Whitestone during Winter's Crest) and pitting the party in a recreational fight against Grog.
- Despite all of the specifics, I would love to get my hands on a formula that I can use in the future.

Comment: What do you mean by "epic-levelled"?

Comment: Oops, I swear I searched for similar questions before posting this. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @L.S.Cooper It's not an easy one to find, apparently: we have several duplicates of it! The more we have, the easier it gets to find though, so thank you for the new wording to help future searchers. :)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie For some reason it didn't turn up on any searches about challenge rating-- I think because it refers mostly to XP, maybe? I always do milestone and tend to forget all about XP as a thing.